# Google BigQuery join issue Query Failed Error: ON clause

Tags: google-bigquery, self-join

Query Failed
Error: ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name. Consider using Standard SQL .google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/), which allows non-equality JOINs and comparisons involving expressions and residual predicates.

Remove last line, this SQL works fine at SQL anywhere/ANSI ..
How to fix this?

```sql
SELECT b.number, b.state 
FROM [bigquery-public-data:usa_names.usa_1910_2013] as a 
join [bigquery-public-data:usa_names.usa_1910_2013] as b
on a.state = b.state 
and b.state = 'WY'
```

Comment: Please use standard SQL and there this runs. Change your tables in backticks `table`

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite  query as

```
SELECT b.number, b.state 
FROM [bigquery-public-data:usa_names.usa_1910_2013] as a 
join 
(select number, state from [bigquery-public-data:usa_names.usa_1910_2013] where state='WY') as b
on a.state = b.state
```

it looks like all the conditions of the `on` clause must have at least 1 column from both tables

Answer (score 0):

The limitation you are facing is specific to BigQuery Legacy SQL dialect
It is quite recommended to [Migrate to BigQuery Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) "dialect"

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and works as expected

```
#standardSQL
SELECT b.number, b.state 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013` AS a 
JOIN `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013` AS b
ON a.state = b.state 
AND b.state = 'WY'
```

Comment: recommended to Migrate to BigQuery Standard SQL "dialect". So I should not use [] table name; and I need to use 'tabe' AS a ... I do use lower case on/and; not ON/ AND. The doc is not clear at all. What is Legacy SQL, I am doing ANSI mostly.